# Roles in django model

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, many-to-many

I have a model in django, in which there will be several roles - regular user, admin and manager. Each of them will be able to do something else. Is the following model OK to work correctly?

```
class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=128)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    admins = models.ManyToManyField(User)
    managers = models.ManyToManyField(User)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work. If the number of roles is large, or dynamic (as in roles can be added, removed, renamed, updated). You could introduce a ternary relation, like:

```
from django.conf import settings

class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)


class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name', max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Membership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    role = models.ForeignKey(Role, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Comment: Great answer. This creates so much possibilities and flexibility. Only it's better to replace     user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
on the membership with     user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE) as per the Django docs.